# how to include another yaml file in base yaml file using yaml-include node.js

Tags: node.js, yaml, swagger

I am trying to include a yaml file in another yaml file using the node module yaml-include but I cannot see any change in any base yaml file

Below is my code

```
var yaml = require('js-yaml');
var yamlinc = require('yaml-include');
var fs = require('fs');
var p = require('path');

yamlinc.setBaseFile(p.join(__dirname, 'baseFile.yaml'));

var src = fs.readFileSync(yamlinc.basefile, 'utf8');

var swagger = yaml.load(src, { filename: p.join(__dirname, 'secondFile.yaml'), filename: yamlinc.basefile });

console.log(JSON.stringify(swagger, null, 2));
```

first yaml file base file

```
---
swagger: "2.0"
info:
  description:
    "some description"

  version: "1"
  title: "test"
host: "localhost.com:8080"
basePath: "/test"
```

my second yaml file looks like

```
-   title: someTitle
        content: |
            The description of title
```

I want to include this swagger yaml file on top of base file, how can I achieve this in by including it in base file

Comment: What is the contents of your first YAML file?

Comment: @Helen, I have updated the question. Actually I have a separate file with all basic documentation with headings. But I could not figure it out how can I include it in yaml file.

Comment: js-yaml does not seem to have YAML merging functionality. You'll want something like [merge-yaml](https://www.npmjs.com/package/merge-yaml) or [merge-config](https://www.npmjs.com/package/merge-config). Also, your second file is not valid YAML - `content` is indented too much; it should be on the same level as `title`.

Comment: use command-line utility like `npm install -g yamlinc` place `$include: secondFile.yaml` into your baseFile.yaml